# Is mysql/docker/zfs safe?

Tags: mysql, docker, zfs

We are looking to use mysql or mariadb within docker on zfs.

I've seen a few old articles that seem to suggest that you need some special configuration options for zfs.

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/57

disable innondb aio
https://hub.docker.com/r/vvoronin/mysql-zfs/dockerfile/

However all these discussions are quite old so I'm unsure if this is still an issue?

Is it safe to run mysql/docker/zfs?
Are any configuration options required for it to be reliable?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any programming content here. This is probably a better fit on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

Historical references seem to contain a few references to OSX, potentially some to WSL2. Consistent behavior from AIO and O_DIRECT though these layers isn't tested by MariaDB. I have no information if MySQL does so or not, so this is going to be a largely MariaDB answer.

The other zfs question you need to ask is is this zfs-fuse or OpenZFS.

MariaDB also doesn't test against any of these in CI (though a [task](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDBF-321) exists to improve coverage).

Recent examples like [MDEV-27900](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27900) show that btrfs, and O_DIRECT (and a bit of uring) can cause unexpected behaviour. This was quite quick to see on a test, however not all errors are [as predicatable/repeatible](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-fsdevel/CABVffEO-29wjA=TKO66nA5JmA-ZnyyLi4VA7BU+B3VoxD8X9DA@mail.gmail.com/T/#u).

Currently I'm working on [MDEV-27593](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27593) improving AIO error handing.

`fallocate` seems to have a fallback implemented.

So for the moment for safety at least on MariaDB, I'd stick to `--innodb_use_native_aio=0` and/or `--innodb_flush_method=fsync` for a little while longer to keep the stronger aspects of the zfs implementation used.

Comment: is there a performance hit for using aio=0 or fsync?

Comment: in a particularly high write intensive workload you might see some degradation. fsync probably aids some read workloads, especially if your innodb-buffer-pool-size is insufficient as it will use OS cache (like postgres) to achieve performance beyond the IO speed.,